# Wordpress - Next and Previous Links No Longer Working

Tags: php, wordpress

On my page I am using the next and previous post link functions and they were working fine but I have just noticed that they are broken and not clickable anymore.

```
previous_post_link('%link','<img id="prev" src="images/prev.png" alt="previous" />', FALSE, '');

next_post_link('%link','<img id="next" src="images/next.png" alt="next" />', FALSE, '');
```

The source on the page seems fine and unchanged, just that the images themselves are no longer clickable:

```
<a href="?p=117" rel="prev"><img id="prev" src="images/prev.png" alt="previous"></a>
<a href="?p=121" rel="next"><img id="next" src="images/next.png" alt="next"></a>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

The only odd thing is that I am using relative positioning on the images to move them to where I want them to be so when I inspect the element, the `a` tag appears miles away from where the actual images are but I am sure this was the case before aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML code is fine, so the problem should be your CSS. 
Try removing the relative positioning to see if they become clickable, can't help you more with just this much code.

Comment: hmm, even using just text instead of an image and removing the positioning doesn't fix it, I can see the text but as if it's behind something... ok, just applied the `z-index` style to it and it's working again now, thanks!